# Convert json response to list

Tags: c#, json, linq, json.net, deserialization

I do a request to a api that I'm using and this is the response that I get back.

```
{ "id": 1139, "performanceStatus": "OK", "availabilityStatus": "OK" }
```

I would like to convert this response in a list where I then can use a for/foreach loop and later can use linq and SelectMany to create a whole new list.

I got this far, but I am stuck the code is not hitting the var "newJson"..

Can someone help me out?

```
var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
dynamic parsedJson = JObject.Parse(json);
    foreach (var j in parsedJson)
    {
        j.Replace(JObject.FromObject(
        new {
            id = j.id,
            performance = j.performanceStatus,
            availability = j.availabilityStatus
            }));
    }

var newJson = parsedJson.ToString();
```

Later I would like to Deserialize it into a strongly typed class. Like so

```
boi = await Task.Run(() => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Boi>(newJson)).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Here is the strongly typed class

```
public class Boi
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string PerformanceStatus { get; set; }

        public string AvailabilityStatus { get; set; }
    }

    public class NewBoi
    { 
        public List<Boi> eeg { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this:

```
        var jsn = "{ \"id\": 1139, \"performanceStatus\": \"OK\", \"availabilityStatus\": \"OK\" }";
        var bois = new List<Boi> { JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Boi>(jsn) };

        var newBoi = new NewBoi() { eeg = bois };
```

Although I would question the need for the NewBoi class - you could just work with the List.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. You are right about the NewBoi class, it is not usefull :)

Answer (score 2):

To deserialize to a well known type use

```
JsonConvert.Deserialize<T>(jsonString,new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
});
```

where T is your well known type.